# Adding a Node to the beginning/start of list

Tags: java, list, nodes

I'm creating a method to add nodes into the list. The method will have the value and the position where the user wants the node. I'm able to add the node anywhere but the start of the list.
I have also added the toString method so there is an idea of how the it is to be displayed. At the bottom I added what main has.

```
//ADD A NODE
public boolean add(double val, int pos)
{
     Node t = root;
     Node n = new Node();
     int count = 1;

     if(pos-1 == 0)
     {
         n.next = t;
         t = n;
         n.val = val;
     } 

     else
     while(t != null)
     {
         if(pos-1 == count)
         {
             n.next = t.next;
             t.next = n;
             n.val = val;
         }
         t = t.next;
         count++;
    }

    return true;
}

 //toString Method
 public String toString()
 {
     String s = "Contents of list: \n";
     if( root == null )
     s = s + "\tThe list is empty!";

     Node t = root;
     while(t != null)
     {
        s = s + t.val + "\t";
        t = t.next;
     }

     return s;   
 }    

//Main
//Add Node to list
  list.add(105.0, 1);
  System.out.println( list );
```

Comment: Whats your expectation

Comment: To add the node to the beginning of the list. It only works when I add it to any other position.

Comment: You need to change change root = n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(pos-1 == 0)
{
    n.next = t;
    root = n;
    n.val = val;
}
```

Fix this so that root is modified.